# Input from main and passing it to a method in java

Tags: java

Below is the code.  I'm a student still and have a question to finish this homework.  I need to have an input from the user done in the "static void main", pass that string to my method "PluralForm", and pass the return back to the "static void main" to print out the result.  I'm stuck in how to pass the string to the method and pass the result back.  Below is the code.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Plural 
{
    public static String PluralForm(String word)
    {

        String last = word.substring(word.length() - 1);
        String sub_last = word.substring(word.length() - 2, word.length() - 1);


        if(last.equals("s") || last.equals("x") || last.equals("z"))
            return word + "es";
        else if(last.equals("h") && sub_last.equals("s") || sub_last.equals("c"))
            return word + "es";
        while(last.equals("y"))
        {
            if(sub_last.equals("a")) return word + "s";
            if(sub_last.equals("e")) return word + "s";
            if(sub_last.equals("i")) return word + "s";
            if(sub_last.equals("o")) return word + "s";
            if(sub_last.equals("u")) return word + "s";
            return word.substring(0, word.length() - 1) + "ies";
        }
        while(last.equals("o"))
        {
            if(sub_last.equals("a")) return word + "s";
            if(sub_last.equals("e")) return word + "s";
            if(sub_last.equals("i")) return word + "s";
            if(sub_last.equals("o")) return word + "s";
            if(sub_last.equals("u")) return word + "s";
            return word + "es";
        }

        return word + "s";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("This program converts an English word to its plural form.\n");
        System.out.print("English word: ");
        ?? ?? ?? = sc.next(???); // how to input and pass the value to the method?


        System.out.println("Plural form: " + ???); //how to print out the return?

    }
}
```

Comment: You use a `while` but return a value anyway? In that case the `while` is pretty useless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
String input = sc.next();
System.out.println("Plural form : " + PluralForm(input));
```

This should work, give it a spin

Comment: indeed you deserve +1 for doing others people homework

Comment: well he hasn't just posted the whole question here and asked for a solution. Its the last step that the OP has been stuck with, I don't see why I shouldn't help him out

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'm loving learning to code.  Sorry for those simple questions.

Comment: Homework was pretty much done.  Just kind of lost at the very end of the problem.

Comment: I see that and hence helped, you might want to accept an answer as the solution.

Comment: @AadiDroid begging for point is forbidden. You cannot force anybody to accept your answer :)

Comment: Accept 'an answer' as a solution, maybe you missed a point :)

Comment: You click on the arrow below the vote counter on the left of the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
String pluralForm = PluralForm(sc.next());
```

will give you the call to the function, and the return value from that function in variable `pluralForm`.

Comment: Just next is what is needed I guess. Is there a nextString method for scanner?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the string to `PluralForm()` as an *argument* (i.e. in the brackets).

*Print* the result by calling something like `System.out.println()` with your method as an argument.